# kettle problem : a parameter value didn't work, using "trans.sendToSlaveServer" to start a trans

Tags: java, transformation, kettle

i'm using

`Trans.setParameterValue("whereStr", "");
Trans.sendToSlaveServer(transMeta, transExecutionConfiguration, rep, null)`
 
to set a Parameter for a kettle Transformation, it will run on a remote server.
However, the remote server can't find the ParameterValue : whereStr.

Any Suggestions？

here is my Transformation setting :
[setting1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wobV.png)
[setting2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZhL7.png)

Comment: problem solved.     1.remove ktr parameters setting 2.using 
 transMeta.addParameterDefinition("whereString", " and a.id > 1000021 ", " whereString");

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
1. remove ktr parameters setting
2. using
`transMeta.addParameterDefinition("whereString", " and a.id > 1000021 ", " whereString");`